# Absolute URL from base folder with rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, relative-path, absolute-path

I have a project running local on WampServer. It's an MVC-like structure; it rewrites the URL to `index.php?url=$1`. Full `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When I want to send the user to another page using PHP `location: <location>` it doesn't do this properly because of the rewriting (all-though I am technically always in `index.php`).

For example if I am on `http://localhost/project_name/controller/method/` and this controller's constructor or method tries to send me to:

- `header('location: another_controller/method');` sends me to
  `http://localhost/project_name/controller/method/another_controller/method/`
- `header('location: /another_controller/method');` sends me to
  `http://localhost/another_controller/method/`

But I want it to send me like this:

- `header('location: /another_controller/method');` sends me to
  `http://localhost/project_name/another_controller/method/`

Now the only solution I have found is:

```
define('BASE_URL','http://localhost/project_name');
header('location: '.BASE_URL.'/another_controller/method/');
```

But this isn't perfect either because it causes me to have to change this defined constant `BASE_URL` whenever the domain or folder name changes. I could also create a method in my `BaseController` that creates absolute URLs, but this method would basically just prepend `BASE_URL` too.

**Note:** The same problem doesn't arise with HTML's `src` and `href` attributes, which can use relative paths (without `project_name` folder in path). I don't understand why however. Because if the header `location` causes the browser to append the the relative-URL to the current location, why doesn't it have the same behavior when looking for `.css` or `.js` files.

**So...** this raises a couple of questions for me:

1. Would I have this problem if I had virtual hosts?
2. What is the best way to solve this problem?
3. Is is best to just have the full absolute URL?
4. Why do HTML's `src` and `href` attributes not share this behavior?

Comment: can you add some code of your htaccess file from starting??

Comment: @HarshSanghani It's added.

Comment: can you please add RewriteBase /project_name/ after RewriteEngine on

Comment: @HarshSanghani This didn't fix it. `header('location: /');` still goes to `http://localhost/` not `http://localhost/project_name/`.

Comment: I noticed you said "`header('location: another_controller/method');` sends me to `http://localhost/project_name/controller/method/another_controller/method/`" I'd like to point out that this will always be the case - you forgot the leading slash. Without the leading slash, it'll always be a relative redirect starting in the present URL. Not sure if this is a typo or completely unrelated, but thought I'd point it out.

Comment: PS - yes, use WAMPServer's built in virtual host functionality to make something like http://project_name/ instead of trying to work around localhost/project_name/ - that's a very frustrating way to do things. You'll fight issue after issue trying to develop in that way. Today it's this issue, tomorrow it's another. Just use WampServer's super easy tool to create a virtual host and be done with the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now the only solution I have found is:
>
> ```
> define('BASE_URL','http://localhost/project_name');
> header('location: '.BASE_URL.'/another_controller/method/');
> ```
>
> But this isn't perfect either because it causes me to have to change
>   this defined constant BASE_URL whenever the domain or folder name
>   changes.

You shouldn't need to change the defined constant. These values can be found dynamically.

**Example:**

```
if ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] == dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])) {
    define('BASE_PATH', '/');
} else {
    define('BASE_PATH', dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) . '/');
}

$protocol = isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
define('BASE_URL', $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . BASE_PATH);
```

Additionally, rather than worrying about whether to specify an absolute URL or a path, you can wrap the redirect into a function which can handle both:

```
function redirect($path = null) {
    if (isset($path)) {
        if (filter_var($path, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            header('Location: ' . $path);
        } else {
            header('Location: ' . BASE_URL . $path);
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: ' . BASE_URL);
    }
    exit;
}
```

Finally, as @HarshSanghani mentioned in the comments, the base path in your `.htaccess` file *should* match the base path in your code. So if `BASE_PATH` (based on the example above) outputs `/project_name/`, then your `.htaccess` should accommodate it:

```
RewriteBase /project_name/
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. It depends on how your virtual hosts would be configured.
2. You could simply generate your BASE_URL dynamically: `$baseUrl = dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);`. This way you won't have to change any code if your folder or domain changes.
3. You don't need the domain part.
4. The html `src` and `href` are interpreted by your browser which takes into account the page's `<base>` tag. All paths on a page with a `<base>` tag get changed accordingly by your browser.

The HTTP headers you send from your server (for redirect) have nothing to do with the html page you send and are therefore not updated.

Answer (score 2):

1. You're going to have this problem if you have your project set up in a subdirectory. Using virtual hosts would be a way round the issue if you wanted to set them up at say, project_name.localhost.
2. In my projects I use an environment variable to load a different config file for development, staging or production. In this I set a `$baseUri` somehow.
3. It's best practice to use the absolute urls (including the domain) for both the solution of this problem and for SEO. In terms of functionality you don't need the domain part.
4. The src and href tags generally work the same way, but as Andreas mentioned they could be affected by the base tag.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify RewriteBase in your htaccess file. Use relative paths in your links and you need nothing more.

```
RewriteBase /project_name/
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```